# What software do I need to develop web parts?

Tags: web-part, 2003

I'm a site collection administrator for my SharePoint site and would like to create a custom web part for my site. I don't have access to the server that's running SharePoint and am unlikely to get any help in that regard.

I have Visual Studio 2008 on my computer. What else do I need to be able to build simple web parts? Will I be able to install and use simple web parts via the web interface or is access to the server and the sysadmin required?

EDIT: Using SharePoint 2003

Answer (score 1):

I never really worked on SharePoint 2003 but find this tutorial for developing a simple webpart for SharePoint 2003 using Visual Studio

[Developing a Simple WebPart 2003](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/17518/1954)

I would also recommend you to read this MSDN article that explains almost everything about webparts in SharePoint 2003

[Webparts in SharePoint 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583154%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

by the way, SharePoint 2013 beta is out and you are looking into development of SharePoint 2003, is there any specific reason for that you would like to share!

Comment: We're using SharePoint 2003 because we just finished upgrading everyone from XP to Win7 and Office 2010 in January. I think we'll be using SharePoint 2010 later this year or next, but I don't know exactly when the SharePoint team plans to perform the upgrade. I'm just using what they provide.

Answer (score 1):

Ok its a bit hard with your criteria, Im guessing you have access to sharepoint central admin?

If not dont worry! you already have everything ;) except for one other thing that will make your life easier! WSPBuilder: http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

Install that, its like an addon to vs2008, you can build and deploy wsp without the need to use stsadm or central admin to add it to the server.

The next part is to make the webpart:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873(v=office.12).aspx

This is a basic example in sharepoint 2003 what is similar if not the same as 2007 and 2010. Making the controls and logic goes into creatChildControls.

build and deploy webpart using WSPBuilder.
http://mathis94.blog.com/2011/07/18/build-your-first-webpart-using-wspbuilder-and-sharepoint-wss-3-0-on-a-64bits-environement/

Adding the webpart to the webpage: 
click on "Adding Web Parts to a Web Part Page" in contents

http://www.fpweb.net/support/archives/sps-sharepoint-portal/sharepoint-portal-2003/install-web-parts/sharepoint-server-2003/#Adding%20Web%20Parts%20to%20a%20Web%20Part%20Page

using wspBuilder means you dont need to access the server as it adds and deploys it for you, you just need to do it on the sharepoint site like adding the webpart.

That is pritty much it hope this helps :)

Comment: All of these links assume I either have SharePoint installed locally (I'm not allowed to do that) or have administrative access to the SharePoint server (I don't). The SharePoint server is run by the IT department at a regional office in another state. I work in IT, but I'm just an end-user of SharePoint at another office and only have "site collection administrator" access to my department's SharePoint site. Is this going to stop me from developing and installing web parts?

Comment: Is there a way a a reference to the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll file without having it? All of these instructions assume I have it.

Comment: yes check out this as someone had the same issue with referencing to the dll http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8b94d229-6872-4b42-880a-c11b00d06edd/ as for adding the webpart using sharepoint ui I dont think its possible but can be wrong! the problem is you need to add the wsp file to the server as stated above.